# Java - using thread with GUI

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

I'm having an issue with my GUI when I try to change the color of a button after 2 seconds when its has been clicked. What I want to do is to click on a white square button, then a color comes up, after 2 seconds I want it to return to it's original color (white). How can achieve this?

My code on click:

```
cards[index].setBackground(cards[index].getTrueColor());
try
{
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    cards[cardPos.get(0)].setBackground(Color.white);
}
catch(Exception e) {}
```

So this goes back to color white, but in an instance, doesn't wait to seconds.
Really appreciate a little help here.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to say what GUI framework you are using. Is it Swing (Desktop), Android (Mobile Phones) or GWT (Web sites)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This calls for a [`Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) instead of `Thread.sleep`. You'll want to set the timer with a delay of 2 seconds, and then have it reset the color of your button. For example, in Swing:

```
// onButtonClick
final Card card = cards[index];
card.setBackground(card.getTrueColor());
new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Change color back
        card.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    } 
}).start();
```

- [How to Use Swing Timers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AsynkTask class in Android. You can use the onPreExecute method to execute the initial task, and then you can wait and change the button color after 2 sec, this can be done in doInBackground method and you can publish the results to UI by calling publish progress method, and finally you can use the onPostExecute method.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html